# Using JavaScript to detect and display HTML content

Tags: javascript, html

Scenario:

I have a site listing prices for a few products - each has a 'full price' and 'sale price' attribute.  If the item isn't on sale, the 'sales price' is simply left blank.

Using JavaScript, I want to display the lowest price for each item (e.g. if there is a sale price display that, otherwise show the full price).

How would I write a script that accomplishes that?

I put an example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enRkR/1237/) to show what I mean.  The lowest price should be displayed in the "pricestory" div.

```
<div class="salePrice" id="saleprice">59.99</div>
<div class="listPrice" id="listprice">70.00</div>
<div class="priceStory" id="pricestory"></div>
```

Comment: I'm thinking it will involve using .innerHTML and conditional logic (if SalePrice != '', then insert ListPrice), but I'm a bit stuck on how to implement for each item using a loop.  Obviously I'm pretty new to JS :)

Comment: You don't need the ids. Wrap every product in a separate container `<div class="products"><div class="product">...</div><div class="product">...</div></div>` to make your live easier.

Comment: In your last example, there is no list price, but there's a sale price... is this an actual possibility, or a typo?

Comment: While I appreciate that it would work - in this case I cannot mess with the HTML/divs.  This is a dumbed down version of a larger problem I'm working on - need a purely JS solution without touching the divs

Comment: @Santi it is an actual possibility

Comment: I wrote you a solution but it was jQuery, prior to realizing you were after a pure JS solution. I'll include the fiddle link in case someone just wants to rewrite it: http://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/enRkR/1239/

Comment: Note that the sales price for the third item in your example is actually *greater than* the list price.

Comment: @j.winslow, your solution could cause problems, because you're comparing strings to strings.  `2` is less than `10`, but `'2'` is greater than `'10`'.  See my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the elements are always in the order:

1. salePrice
2. listPrice
3. priceStory

…, you can iterate through all the `salePrice` items, and use [**nextElementSibling**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) to set the `priceStory` content as needed:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.salePrice'), function(sp) {
  var salePrice = sp.textContent || Infinity,  //default to Infinity if missing, 
                                               //so Math.min will use listPrice
      listPrice = sp.nextElementSibling.textContent || Infinity;

  sp.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.textContent = Math.min(salePrice, listPrice);
});
```

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.salePrice'), function(sp) {
  var salePrice = sp.textContent || Infinity,  //default to Infinity, so Math.min will use listPrice
      listPrice = sp.nextElementSibling.textContent || Infinity;
  
  sp.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.textContent = Math.min(salePrice, listPrice);
});
```

```css
.salePrice {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #777777;
}

.listPrice {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000000;
}

.priceStory {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #777777;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="products">
  <div class="salePrice" id="saleprice">59.99</div>
  <div class="listPrice" id="listprice">70.00</div>
  <div class="priceStory" id="pricestory"></div>


  <div class="salePrice" id="saleprice2"></div>
  <div class="listPrice" id="listprice2">70.00</div>
  <div class="priceStory" id="pricestory2"></div>

  <div class="salePrice" id="saleprice3">79.99</div>
  <div class="listPrice" id="listprice3">70.00</div>
  <div class="priceStory" id="pricestory3"></div>

  <div class="salePrice" id="saleprice4">35.99</div>
  <div class="listPrice" id="listprice4"></div>
  <div class="priceStory" id="pricestory4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great - many thanks for the link to documentation on nextElementSibling.  Very useful and good to know!

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS solution: http://jsfiddle.net/upyjdym9/

```
.listPrice {
   display: none;
}     
.salePrice:empty + .listPrice {
  display: block;
}
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Nope, I'm looking for a JavaScript solution

Comment: A CSS-only solution is generally preferable to a JavaScript solution.  +1

Comment: He wants a third div to be populated with the lower price of the two before it... it's physically impossible to do in CSS.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought a CSS version would be better. Then, as Andreas said in his comment, it would be better to wrap each product in its own div to make sure we have both values coupled together. Are you using jQuery or pure JS?

Edit: I must have missed the last part of his question about populating the last div, sorry.

Comment: No worries, it's an admittedly strange scenario.  Using pure JS, no jQuery

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution.

```js
var salePriceElements = document.getElementsByClassName('salePrice');  
var listPriceElements = document.getElementsByClassName('listPrice');
var priceStoryElements = document.getElementsByClassName('priceStory')

for (var i = 0; i < salePriceElements.length; i++) {
  var salePrice = salePriceElements[i].innerHTML;  
  var listPrice = listPriceElements[i].innerHTML;
  
  var priceStory = listPrice || salePrice;
  if (listPrice && salePrice) {
  priceStory = listPrice > salePrice ? salePrice : listPrice;
  }
  
  priceStoryElements[i].innerHTML = priceStory;
}
```

```css
.salePrice{
  font-family:arial;
  font-size: 12px; 
  color:#777777;  
 }  
 .listPrice{
  font-family:arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  color:#000000;
 }
 .priceStory{
  font-family:arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  color:#777777;
  margin-bottom:20px;
 }
 #explanation{
  font-family:arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  color:#777777;   
 }
```

```html
<div class="products">
  <div class="salePrice" id="saleprice">59.99</div>
  <div class="listPrice" id="listprice">70.00</div>
  <div class="priceStory" id="pricestory"></div>

  <div class="salePrice" id="saleprice2"></div>
  <div class="listPrice" id="listprice2">70.00</div>
  <div class="priceStory" id="pricestory2"></div>

  <div class="salePrice" id="saleprice3">79.99</div>
  <div class="listPrice" id="listprice3">70.00</div>
  <div class="priceStory" id="pricestory3"></div>

  <div class="salePrice" id="saleprice4">35.99</div>
  <div class="listPrice" id="listprice4"></div>
  <div class="priceStory" id="pricestory4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good solution, but you added a new div for each product.  Definitely makes things easier, but not exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks though!

Comment: This is a good solution if the elements aren't always in the same order.  But you should convert the `salePrice` and `listPrice` to numbers, because  `2` is less than `10`, but `'2'` is greater than `'10'`.

Comment: @Rick Hitchcock Yes, you're right, I missed it. Thanks for your comment.